# Azure returns 503, but access logs report 200

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm encountering some weird behaviour on my Azure website. We poll a test action regularly. In our tests we record several 503s. When I correlate the reported times to the Azure access logs I see a status code of 200 in the Azure access logs, with a particularly long request processing time ~24 seconds.

Has anyone encountered this? Could it be that the website VM returns the request, but a time out period set by Azure has already passed so it has returned 503 to the client?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are no failed request logs or error events on the IIS server, so I am 99.99843% sure that this is a problem with Azure.

Comment: Transient errors can and do happen in public cloud environments. You are probably witnessing this in the Azure Websites context. The architecture is such that you might get a 503 (or similar) error code from the Websites front-end but the actual Website instance (sitting behind the front-end services) will return a 200.  If you consistently see this try moving the site to another instance OR open a support ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: We were not able to figure out the source of the problem, but we were able to fix it by implementing simple retry on failure.